Syntax Postgresql query
Im trying make a sql query.

get last row from today, insert new row with +1 on management_number. (working)
create a first today row if not found any row. (not working).

my code is:
with rows as 
(

select management_number 
from management
where created_at >= '2024-07-19' and type = 'NORMAL' 
ORDER BY management_number DESC LIMIT 1

)

INSERT INTO management(type, management_number)
SELECT 'NORMAL', management_number + 1

FROM rows 
RETURNING *

can someone help me with this code?


The LIMIT should be in the CTE. But what you are trying to do is not a good idea: it will fail reliably if there are two concurrent inserts. Use a sequence.

What is where created_at >= '2024-07-19' for?

Can we see the schema for management, please? Do \d+ management in psql.

Please don't change the question based on people's suggestions in the comments. It gets really confusing.

created_at >= '2024-07-19' => is today example

now can understand now what I need?

Is management_number unique or per day? For example, if you had a management_number 5 on 2024-07-18, and you insert a new row on 2024-07-19 would it be 6 or 1?

management_number IS NOT UNIQUE, every day will have 1,2,3... every First day row need be 1


get last row from today...

Right now you have a hard coded date. Instead, use current_date, cast created_at to a date, and check if they're equal.
You can make this a little simpler by using max.
select max(management_number)
from management
where created_at::date = current_date 
  and type = 'NORMAL'

You'll also want to make sure you've made that unique per day.
create unique index management_number_uniq_by_day on management(management_number, (created_at::date));

insert into management(management_number, created_at) values(1, now());

ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "management_number_uniq_by_day"
DETAIL:  Key (management_number, (created_at::date))=(1, 2024-07-19) already exists.


To do the rest of the logic, look for today's max management_number. If it exists, add 1 and insert. If not, use 1. You can do this with coalesce which will pick the first non-null value.
You don't need a CTE, you can insert from select.
insert into management(management_number)
select coalesce(max(management_number)+1, 1)
from management
where created_at::date = current_date 
  and type = 'NORMAL';

If there are no rows for that date, max(management_number) will be null and coalesce(max(management_number)+1, 1) will return 1.
This query assumes created_at has a default current_timestamp which it should. If not, you'll have to do that manually (or better, add the default).
Demonstration.

I have to do a litle chage but I think its working. insert into management(type,management_number)
select 'NORMAL', coalesce(max(management_number)+1, 1)
from management
where created_at >= '2024-07-19'
and type = 'NORMAL' RETURNING *;
I need pass date value but thanks for all

@HimorriveL I assumed type would have a sensible default.

@HimorriveL where created_at >= '2024-07-19'  this is not entirely correct. It will pick up everything from 2024-07-19 onward. If run after 2024-07-19 it will pick up multiple days. Use where created_at::date = '2024-07-19' to always only pick up one day.
